# How to limit a text by characters

Tags: php, laravel

I have a PHP project ( Using laravel ) and  I need to show just part of an article in the view . For example this is the full content of article :

> Hello World It is my First Post and I decided to share it on my
>   personal blog .

and I wanted to show part of that in the recent posts part such this :

> Hello world it is ...

I made a function but it doesn't work when I want to limit the text ( But there is no problem with short texts )  This is my function :

```
function limitText($text,$length=300) {
    if(strlen($text)<$length) {
        $new = $text."...";
        return $new;
    }
    $new = substr($text,0,$length);
    $new = $new."...";
    return $new; }
```

any idea or suggestion ?

Comment: I use this: `reg_replace ( "/[^ ]*$/", '', substr ( $content, 0, ($maxChars - $puffer) ) ) . " ...";`

Comment: it works - https://eval.in/756714

Comment: reg_replace -> It says the function is not defined

Comment: Thanks I replaced it with preg_replace and it worked ... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do that is to use [`str_limit()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-str-limit)

```
$value = str_limit('Just string', 4, '...'); // Output is 'Just...'
```

> The `str_limit` function limits the number of characters in a string. The function accepts a string as its first argument and the maximum number of resulting characters as its second argument